# Make nss_ldap use STARTTLS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, ldap

I'm trying to set up **LDAP authentication with STARTTLS** (I read that TLS/ldaps was deprecated). BTW unencrypted LDAP authentication works but that's not what I want.

I managed to set up an LDAP directory server using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-openldap-connections-using-starttls) starting from a fresh Ubuntu Server 16.10 install (2 VirtualBox machines, one for the server, one for the client) and followed every step including the optional last step to only allow TLS connections.

Now I can run `ldapwhoami` and `ldapsearch` commands with `-Z` argument on both the server and the client. So it seems LDAP connections to the server via STARTTLS work. When I try to connect without `-Z` I get the following (expected) error:

```
Confidentiality required (13)
Additional information: TLS confidentiality required
```

Now I want to use the server to authenticate LDAP users on the client. For this I ran the following commands **on the client**:

```
sudo apt-get install ldap-auth-client
# LDAP Server: ldap://ldap.example.com
# Base DN:     dc=example,dc=com
# Bind DN:     cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

sudo auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap

sudo vi /usr/share/pam-configs/mkhomedir
# changed "Default: no" to "Default: yes"
# changed "optional" to "required"

sudo pam-auth-update
# enabled "Create home directory on login"
```

Now when I want to change the user on the client with `su - otheruser` the following error message is appended to `/var/log/auth.log` on the client:

```
nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://ldap.example.com: Confidentiality required
```

This is the same error message as when I try to run LDAP commands without STARTTLS (see above), so the problem seems to be that `nss_ldap` is not configured correctly to use STARTTLS.

What I tried (without success) is to add entries to `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`. Now it looks like this:

```
BASE         dc=example,dc=com
URI          ldap://ldap.example.com
TLS_CACERT   /etc/ldap/ca_certs.pem
LDAP_VERSION 3
SSL          start_tls
TLS_REQCERT  allow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poking around the client configuration I accidentally opened `/etc/ldap.conf` instead of `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` and was surprised that both exist!

The file `/etc/ldap.conf` is generated by debconf, i.e. when calling `sudo apt-get install ldap-auth-client` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config`, and seems to be the one used by nss_ldap. It contains many commented options.

Since STARTTLS does not seem to be supported by the debconf wizard I changed the following in `/etc/ldap.conf`:

- removed the first line `###DEBCONF###`
- uncommented the line `ssl start_tls`

Now authentication on the client finally works.